# ClassCastException in android.widget.AutoTextComplete

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
public class Review extends Activity {

    private CustomAutoCompleteView autoComplete;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.review);

        System.out.print("1");
        autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        System.out.print("2");
        autoCompleteAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); d
        autoComplete = (CustomAutoCompleteView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);/*Line which is unable to cast throws Exception*/
        autoComplete.setHint("Restaurant Name");
        autoComplete.setThreshold(3);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);

        final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}
```

### CustomAutoCompleteView.java

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context) {
super(context);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
String filterText = "";
super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
}
/**
* After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing
* text
*/
@Override
protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
super.replaceText(text);
}
}
```

> ***I am unable to cast AutoCompleteText class into CustomAutoCompleteView.Even though the class CustomAutoCompleteView contains a matching constructer.It throws a run time exception.Please Help me.***

Comment: <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/restaurantname_autocomplete">

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

Comment: This is my review.xml file you can check out the id of the widget.

Comment: It is like, < <your_package_name>.CustomAutoCompleteView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/restaurantname_autocomplete"> <requestFocus />  </<your_package>.AutoCompleteTextView>

Comment: look at my comment change accordingly it.

Comment: Instead of <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" i need to write<CustomAutoCompleteView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"

Comment: it start with your package name... what is your application's package name?

Answer (score 0):

If class `B` extends `A` then class `B` can be cast to class `A` because there is a guarantee that all instances of `B` are also instances of `A`. However, you cannot guarantee that an instance of `A` is a `B` therefore a cast from `A` to `B` could throw a `ClassCastException` if you have not first used `instanceof` to verify that the instance of `A` is actually an instance of `B`.

The statement about the construct if not applicable because casting does not utilize contructors and the object already exists.